# docker --cache-from with BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE does not work every second time

Tags: docker, caching, docker-registry

I am trying to take advantage of the caching/pulling system of BUILDKIT for Docker for my CI/CD process. But it does not work as expected.
I created a dummy local example (but the same happens also in my CI system - AWS CodePipeline, and for both DockerHub and AWS ECR).
The Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add and install requirements
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip $PIP_PROXY install --no-cache-dir --compile -r requirements.txt

RUN echo 123
# add app
COPY ./run_test.py /usr/src/app/run_test.py

# run server
CMD ["python", "run_test.py"]
```

run_test.py is actually not interesting, but here is the code just in case:

```
import requests
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(requests)
```

Also you need to create an empty `requirements.txt` file in the same folder.
In advance, I export two environment variables:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1  # to activate buildkit
export DUMMY_IMAGE_URL=bi0max/test_docker
```

Then, to test I have the following command. First two commands remove local cache to resemble the CI environment, then build and push.
BE CAREFUL, CODE BELOW REMOVES LOCAL BUILD CACHE:

```
docker builder prune -a -f && \
(docker image rm $DUMMY_IMAGE_URL:latest || true) && \
docker build \
--cache-from $DUMMY_IMAGE_URL:latest \
--build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 \
--tag $DUMMY_IMAGE_URL:latest "." && \
docker push $DUMMY_IMAGE_URL:latest
```

As expected, the first run just builds everything from scratch:

```
#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 434B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.1s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim
#3 DONE 0.0s

#12 [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim
#12 DONE 0.0s

#7 [internal] load build context
#7 DONE 0.0s

#4 importing cache manifest from bi0max/test_docker:latest
#4 ERROR: docker.io/bi0max/test_docker:latest not found

#12 [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim
#12 resolve docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim done
#12 DONE 0.0s

#7 [internal] load build context
#7 transferring context: 204B done
#7 DONE 0.1s

#5 [2/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/app
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [3/7] RUN pip install --upgrade pip
#6 1.951 Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (20.1.1)
#6 DONE 2.3s

#8 [4/7] COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
#8 DONE 0.0s

#9 [5/7] RUN pip $PIP_PROXY install --no-cache-dir --compile -r requirement...
#9 0.750 Collecting requests==2.22.0
#9 0.848   Downloading requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
#9 0.932 Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
#9 0.948   Downloading idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
#9 0.995 Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
#9 1.011   Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
#9 1.135 Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
#9 1.153   Downloading urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
#9 1.264 Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
#9 1.282   Downloading certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
#9 1.378 Installing collected packages: idna, chardet, urllib3, certifi, requests
#9 1.916 Successfully installed certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.9
#9 DONE 2.2s

#10 [6/7] RUN echo 123
#10 0.265 123
#10 DONE 0.3s

#11 [7/7] COPY ./run_test.py /usr/src/app/run_test.py
#11 DONE 0.0s

#13 exporting to image
#13 exporting layers done
#13 writing image sha256:f98327afae246096725f7e54742fe9b25079f1b779699b099e66c8def1e19052 done
#13 naming to docker.io/bi0max/test_docker:latest done
#13 DONE 0.0s

#14 exporting cache
#14 preparing build cache for export done
#14 DONE 0.0s
```

Then, I slightly adjust `run_test.py` file and the result is again as expected. All the layers until the last step ([7/7] COPY) are downloaded from repository and reused.

```
#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 434B done
#1 DONE 0.1s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim
#3 DONE 0.0s

#8 [internal] load build context
#8 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 importing cache manifest from bi0max/test_docker:latest
#5 DONE 1.2s

#8 [internal] load build context
#8 transferring context: 193B done
#8 DONE 0.0s

#6 [2/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/app
#6 CACHED

#7 [3/7] RUN pip install --upgrade pip
#7 CACHED

#9 [4/7] COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
#9 CACHED

#10 [5/7] RUN pip $PIP_PROXY install --no-cache-dir --compile -r requirement...
#10 CACHED

#11 [6/7] RUN echo 123
#11 pulling sha256:79fc69c08b391d082b4d2617faed489d220444fa0cf06953cdff55c667866bed
#11 pulling sha256:071624272167ab4e35a30eb1640cb3f15ced19c6cd10fa1c9d49763372e81c23
#11 pulling sha256:04ed4ecd76e1a110f468eb1a3173bbfa578c6b4c85a6dc82bf4a489ed8b8c54d
#11 pulling sha256:79fc69c08b391d082b4d2617faed489d220444fa0cf06953cdff55c667866bed 0.2s done
#11 pulling sha256:d6406c1ce2dc5e841233ebce164ee469388102cb98f1473adaeca15455d6d797
#11 pulling sha256:071624272167ab4e35a30eb1640cb3f15ced19c6cd10fa1c9d49763372e81c23 0.5s done
#11 pulling sha256:04ed4ecd76e1a110f468eb1a3173bbfa578c6b4c85a6dc82bf4a489ed8b8c54d 0.5s done
#11 pulling sha256:4f4fb700ef54461cfa02571ae0db9a0dc1e0cdb5577484a6d75e68dc38e8acc1
#11 pulling sha256:d6406c1ce2dc5e841233ebce164ee469388102cb98f1473adaeca15455d6d797 0.3s done
#11 pulling sha256:4f4fb700ef54461cfa02571ae0db9a0dc1e0cdb5577484a6d75e68dc38e8acc1 0.2s done
#11 CACHED

#12 [7/7] COPY ./run_test.py /usr/src/app/run_test.py
#12 DONE 0.0s

#13 exporting to image
#13 exporting layers done
#13 writing image sha256:f37692114f10b9a3646203569a0849af20774651f4aa0f5dc8d6f133fb7ff062 done
#13 naming to docker.io/bi0max/test_docker:latest done
#13 DONE 0.0s

#14 exporting cache
#14 preparing build cache for export done
#14 DONE 0.0s
```

Now, I change `run_test.py` again and I would expect docker to do the same thing as last time. But I get the following result, where it build everything from scratch:

```
#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 434B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim
#3 DONE 0.0s

#5 [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim
#5 DONE 0.0s

#8 [internal] load build context
#8 DONE 0.0s

#4 importing cache manifest from bi0max/test_docker:latest
#4 DONE 1.7s

#8 [internal] load build context
#8 transferring context: 182B done
#8 DONE 0.0s

#5 [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim
#5 resolve docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim done
#5 DONE 0.1s

#6 [2/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/app
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [3/7] RUN pip install --upgrade pip
#7 1.774 Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (20.1.1)
#7 DONE 2.1s

#9 [4/7] COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
#9 DONE 0.0s

#10 [5/7] RUN pip $PIP_PROXY install --no-cache-dir --compile -r requirement...
#10 0.805 Collecting requests==2.22.0
#10 0.905   Downloading requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
#10 1.079 Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
#10 1.109   Downloading urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
#10 1.242 Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
#10 1.259   Downloading certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
#10 1.336 Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
#10 1.353   Downloading idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
#10 1.410 Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
#10 1.428   Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
#10 1.545 Installing collected packages: urllib3, certifi, idna, chardet, requests
#10 2.102 Successfully installed certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.9
#10 DONE 2.4s

#11 [6/7] RUN echo 123
#11 0.259 123
#11 DONE 0.3s

#12 [7/7] COPY ./run_test.py /usr/src/app/run_test.py
#12 DONE 0.0s

#13 exporting to image
#13 exporting layers done
#13 writing image sha256:f4ffb0e84e334b4b35fe2504de11012e5dc1ca5978eace055932e9bbbe83c93e done
#13 naming to docker.io/bi0max/test_docker:latest done
#13 DONE 0.0s

#14 exporting cache
#14 preparing build cache for export done
#14 DONE 0.0s
```

But the strangest thing for me is, when I change `run_test.py` for the third time, it uses cached layers again. And it continues in the same way: fourth time - doesn't use, fifth time - uses, etc...

Do I miss something here?

If I pull the image each time before building, then it always uses cache, but it also works in the same way without the BUILDKIT.

Comment: Did you post this on buildkit's github issues? Were you able to fix this?

Comment: @GermanLashevich, unfortunately I was not able to fix this. No, I did not post it on github issues. Do you have a similar problem?

Comment: yes, I bumped into similar issue yesterday. Though, in my case it doesn't use the cache randomly, not on every even run.

Comment: @GermanLashevich, added the issue on github, if you are interested: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1981

Comment: not working ever

Answer (score 4):

This issue got fixed in newer docker versions, a simple upgrade resolves the issue.

Otherwise the solution described on GitHub can help to not rely on the systems docker version: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1981#issuecomment-785534131

Comment: Actually, it still doesn't work. I have latest docker engine v20.10.7, but my example still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the inline cache image becomes invalid (or incomplete) if it was built while reusing the cache. It's either a limitation or a bug.

There is a workaround: you can tag a *distinct* cache image, that you'll only push to the registry when BuildKit has rebuilt the image. AFAIK there is no mean to know whether BuildKit used the cache or not, but we can see the log is filled with CACHED when it did, so we can reuse it. For example:

```
# enable buildkit:
$ export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1

# build image trying to use cache image + build cache image:
$ docker build . \
  --tag image:latest \
  --tag image:build-cache \
  --use-cache-from=image:build-cache \
  --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE = 1 \
  | tee docker.log

# push new image to the registry:
docker push image:latest

# trick: only push cache image to the registry if it was rebuilt:
grep -q CACHED docker.log || docker push image:build-cache
```

Comment: Clever.... Did [4796](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/4796) finally fix `#2274` 5 days ago

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by building the image with Buildah.

It works with the cache reliably and predictably, unlike Docker (still after those years).

My code for use in GitLab CI looks like:

```bash
before_script:
    - buildah login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
script:
    - buildah build
        --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/app:latest
        --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/app # No tag here
        --layers
        --cache-to $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/app # No tag here
        .
    - buildah push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/app:latest
```

The cache is stored in the GitLab registry separate from the app image.

I spent many hours by researching and testing this.

**What's also recommended is to have the ".dockerignore" file with `.git*`**

Using Kaniko is another good solution but Buildah is closer to default Docker commands (1:1 replacement) and can be easily added into default DinD image.